# How to disable resize button in winjs

Tags: win-universal-app, winjs, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-universal

I'm developing windows 10 cordova application and for native integration we should use WinJS. I would like to know below things in Winjs app.

1. How to disable resize button in app control bar?
2. How to set maximum windows during application load?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271591/disable-fullscreen-maximise-button-in-uwp-application

Comment: Can you update your post to change "app control bar" to "window title bar"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in UWP to manipulate with windowing buttons (e.g. disable them). To control window size you can use the following three methods:

1. [setPrefferedMinSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize) to define minimum window size (up to 500x500px).
2. [tryResizeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview) to manually attempt to resize windows to desired size.
3. [tryEnterFullScreenMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode.aspx) to place app in full-screen mode.

There is [a code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ResizeAppView) for these methods, including JS.

Comment: I just want to disable or hide resize button winJS. I tried above options but my client doesn't accepting.

Comment: As I said from documentation perspective and from my own experience there is no way to manipulate with windowing buttons in the window title bar in UWP. The only two things you can change in the title bar are: 1) title itself and 2) colors.