# how to recreate feedback window from edge native app in my own UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image: Edge browser's feedback looks like this]

it is a window with only a close button and fixed size.
How can we create the same from a UWP app(XAML and c#).
UWP API's are not allowing for window size to be fixed , and even we cant disable the minimise and maximise buttons from a window title bar

Comment: The new Microsoft Edge app is not a UWP app, it's a Win32 packaged app.

Comment: can i recreate a similar control with uwp?

Comment: If you mean fixed size window and hiding maximize button, you are out of luck. There are workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065512/how-to-set-fixed-window-size-for-universal-windows-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271591/disable-fullscreen-maximise-button-in-uwp-application) but nowhere near a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

UWP is based on Page, which is different from win32 applications (they usually consist of `Form` or `Window`). According to your needs, I recommend that you use the `ContentDialog` control, which can simulate such a feedback window and provide a similar experience. Here is an example:

**FeedbackDialog.xaml**

```xml
<ContentDialog
    ...
    Title="Send Feedback"
    PrimaryButtonText="Send"
    CloseButtonText="Cancel"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">

    <Grid MaxWidth="400">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Header="Describe what's happening" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True"
                         MinHeight="160" PlaceholderText="Remember not to include personal info like phone numbers"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="DescribeTextBox"/>
                
                <TextBox Header="URL" Margin="0,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                         x:Name="UrlTextBox"/>
                
                <CheckBox Content="Include email address" Margin="0,15,0,0" x:Name="EmailEnabledCheckBox"/>
                <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=EmailEnabledCheckBox,Path=IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Margin="0,10,0,0" x:Name="EmailAddressTextBox"/>
                
                <!-- other controls... -->
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

If we have a feedback button, we can use it like this

**Usage**

```cs
private async void FeedbackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new FeedbackDialog();
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Using `ContentDialog` to create forms is a common practice in UWP. For longer forms, you can add `ScrollViewer` to scroll the content when the Dialog is not high enough.

Its style is somewhat different from the style of the Edge browser you provide, you can modify it on this basis.

Comment: yes content dialog can help create a similar control, but the window properties will be missed though(moving the window by dragging the title bar kind of actions). hope microsoft adds support to create customised window in UWP too.

Comment: Hello, UWP can create windows through `ApplicationView`. 18362 supports the new `AppWindow`. For the specific creation method, you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views).